# wicket AjaxLink onclick not responding

Tags: ajax, hyperlink, window, wicket, modal-dialog

I'm building a website with wicket. I have a modal window that opens from an ajaxlink from the main page. The problem is that when I added a CSS to my HTML code in order to make it more visible attractive, it stopped working. So now, when I click in the AjaxLink that opens the modal window, nothing happens and I can't figure out why. Any Ideas??

This is the code of the AjaxLink:

```
AjaxLink privacyLink = new AjaxLink<Void>("privacylink") {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        modal2.show(target);
    }
};
```

One more comment. This AjaxLink is introduced as a part of a ListView, so actually there are multiple AjaxLinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution!!, It was a problem of the version of jQuery that I was using (1.4.2) so I just changed it to 1.5.2 and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In order for the AjaxLink to refresh you will need to call something along the lines of:

```
modal2.setVisible(true);
target.addComponent(modal2Container);
```

Where modal2 is the component that you want to control the visibility of, and modal2Container is a WebMarkupContainer with .setOutputMarkupId(true) that modal2 is added to when the page/panel is constructed.

I have found the examples at http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-1.4.x/ajax/ to be particularly useful (I'm using 1.4, but there are other examples for whichever version of wicket you are running you can get to from http://wicketstuff.org/).

Comment: I'm not pretty sure of where you want me to add those lines :S. Also, my modal window is based in the second modal window found in  http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-1.4.x/ajax/ and is still not working. Even I put a System.out.println(); inside the onclick in order to see if at least gets inside this function, but nothing is printed, so thats why I said that the onClick function is not working... Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: @OnesAndZeros This approach does not apply for the ModalWindow component!

Comment: I know, I only need one modal window. The problem is not that. The problem is that somehow the AjaxLink is not working. I just test it adding one AjaxLink outside the listview and triying to print something from it, and nothig happens...

Comment: Sorry, Misread the question.  I only use a modal window in the following way:
<code>submitButton.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure?');")); </code>  I suppose you could do more with the javascript if you wanted...  What css did you add? What does the html markup look like?

Comment: I finally found the solution!!, It was a problem of the version of jQuery that I was using (1.4.2) so I just changed it to 1.5.2 and it worked!