# Wicket AjaxLink in Modal Window doesn´t work

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I am trying to add an AjaxLink inside a `ModalWindow`. This AjaxLink is used to do some stuff like deleting something off the database and finally close the `ModalWindow`.

I added the `ModalWindow` accordording to the Wicket examples: [Link to examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/ajax/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?1&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.modal.ModalWindowPage&source=ModalContent1Page.java). But this doesn´t work.

My MainPage:

```
    public class EventPanel extends Panel {
            // some stuff happens here, the constructor accepts the eventModel
            final ModalWindow modal;
            add(modal = new ModalWindow("modal"));
            modal.setCookieName("modal-1");

            modal.setPageCreator(new ModalWindow.PageCreator() {
                public Page createPage() {
                    // Use this constructor to pass a reference of this page.
                    return new DeleteEventWindow(eventModel, modal);
                }
            });

            modal.setCloseButtonCallback(new ModalWindow.CloseButtonCallback() {
                public boolean onCloseButtonClicked(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    // Change the passValue variable when modal window is closed.

                    return true;
                }
            });

            // Add the link that opens the modal window.
            add(new AjaxLink<Void>("showModalLink") {
                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    modal.show(target);
                }
            });
      }
```

Modal Window:

```
    public class DeleteEventWindow extends WebPage {

           public DeleteEventWindow(final IModel<Event> model,
                                    final ModalWindow window) {

              // some stuff happens

              // this link doesn´t work
              add(new AjaxLink<Void>("closeOK") {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                 // Just a print to console for debugging
                  System.out.println("nooo");
                  window.close(target);
               }
        });

    }
  }
```

ModalWindow HTML

```
   <html>
          <head>
              <title>Modal Content Page</title>
          </head>
   <body>
    <!-- some other fields output --!>
    <a wicket:id="closeOK">close</a><br/>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The `ModalWindow` itself works fine, also the link is rendered. But if I click onto it, the `onClick` function doesn´t seem to be triggered. I also tried a normal `Link`, this works fine..

I also found this question : [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157818/wicket-ajaxlink-onclick-not-responding), but I am using JQuery 1.9.1..

Comment: Does the browser console output any information?

Comment: no nothing at all. `System.out.println("nooo");` is not printed, thats why I assume, the `onClick` method isn´t triggered.

Comment: `browser console != Java console` i was thinking about javascript issues that occur in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not giving enough information; you have the modal window added to an item (row Item I assume), but the link to show the modal is added to the panel.

Comment: ups, I forgot to delete that `item`. But yes you are right, it is a row item. I just wanted to shorten the code for this post. The `Modal Window` works like this. There is not more code which is necessary for the `modal window`.